# plot a figure using "for" loop from different files

Tags: matlab

I tried to plot a figure from two files each time. So, I used "for" loop trying to plot each time but something wrong in my code, considering the fact that I am new in Matlab. Here is the code before applying the loop.

```
load FA1.m 
load FA2.m

load FAER.m

FAm=FA1(:,1)
FAu=FA1(:,2)


FAam=FA2(:,1)
FAau=FA2(:,2)


ER=FAER(:,1)

figure
  plot(ER,FAm,'LineWidth',2);
  hold on;
  plot(ER,FAu,'LineWidth',2);
  hold off;
  grid on

  figure
    plot(ER,FAam,'LineWidth',2);
  hold on;
  plot(ER,FAau,'LineWidth',2);
  hold off;
  grid on
```

After applying the loop, it didn't work properly. Here is the code:

````
for i=1:2
FAm=FAi(:,1)
FAu=FAi(:,2)
ER=FAER(:,1)

figure
plot(ER,FAm,'LineWidth',2)
hold on
plot(ER,FAu,'LineWidth',2)
hold off
grid on```
````

Comment: `but something wrong considering the fact that I am not a master in Matlab.` This doesn't explain what went wrong. Could you tell us what output you're getting along with what you're expecting?

Comment: I have four files FA1,FA2,FA3 and FA4. So, every loop i want it to enter i.e. FA1 then plot and again enter FA2 and plot ..etc. however, it said error first line after “for”.

Comment: I am not sure how to use “i” to be substituted by 1,2,3 and 4.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want code like below?

```
figure;
for i = 1:4
  load(["FA",num2str(i),".m"]);
  plot(FAER(:,1),FA(:,i),'LineWidth',2);
  hold on;
end
hold off;
grid on;
```